# Understanding failed connection reason

Tags: google-compute-engine, tcpdump

Edit: The issue came about because our machines did not have external IP address and so outgoing traffic was going through Cloud NAT, which was misconfigured (min connections per vm)

I am having issues with a GCP machine being able to connect to an external HTTP server. Below is a line from tcpdump

```
16:17:26.561616 IP 2.2.2.2 > 3.3.3.3.http: Flags [S], seq 1152634327, win 28400, options [mss1420,sackOK,TS val3415260604 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:17:26.561736 IP 1.1.1.1 > 2.2.2.2: ICMP host 3.3.3.3 unreachable - admin prohibited filter, length 68

1.1.1.1 is a GCP gateway
2.2.2.2 is my machine on GCP
3.3.3.3 is the external server
```

How do I know which machine is enforcing the rule that blocks the connection attempt?

Comment: It's probably the machine that the ICMP message came from. That's what it is in every other case. BTW, you should not fake RFC1918 addresses, nor use other people's public IP addresses as examples. See [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963) for details and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCP has 2 implied rules stated in the [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules) . The implied egress rule permits all the egress traffic with the lowest priority (65535).

I have replicated the scenario an placed a firewall rule to my GCP project (wheew is my GCP VM source address) denying all the egress traffic to a specific external address (x.x.x.x), I got that TCPdump (performed over my instance) shows reattempts of connection:

Where x.x.x.x is an external IP and vminstance is my GCP Instance.

18:19:50.499009 IP vminstance.39728 > x.x.x.x.80: Flags [S], seq 1309572437, win 28400, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 323066870 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

18:19:51.527849 IP vminstance.39728 > x.x.x.x.80: Flags [S], seq 1309572437, win 28400, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 323067128 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

So stated that, and compared to your output you may want to look the remote network/host firewall rules

Comment: Turns out the issue was due to a misconfigured GCP NAT gateway.